# Azure deployment issue after solution conversion to VS2017

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure-web-app-service

I have a .net core web app written using VS2015 and deployed in Azure. 
Recently I have moved to VS2017 and it forced me to convert my web app solution so that I can develop it in new VS. I did this and there were no issues. 
Then I made a minor change in my app and commited that change to github. Once I did it, Azure has started to build new version as it is configured to automatically deploy current version of app from github. 
the issue is that after solution conversion to VS2017 i cannot deploy it in azure. I constantly get an error:

> D:\home\site\repository\WebApp\src\WebApp\WebApp.csproj(84,5): error
>   MSB3073: The command "dotnet bundle" exited with code 1. Failed
>   exitCode=1, command=dotnet publish "WebApp\src\WebApp\WebApp.csproj"
>   --output "D:\local\Temp\8d481c16c48679f" --configuration Release

Can any one help me, I'm not very experienced in VS IDE, I think it might be something with project properties or references.

thank you in advance

Comment: can you show more about the error message and what's on line `WebApp.csproj(84,5)`? if you opened an issue on [kudu github](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues) (following the issue template), I can take a look at your project structure

Answer (score 2):

In the .csproj file, please get rid of any references to "dotnet bundle" as well as the NuGet package "BundlerMinifier.Core". When you've done that and it compiles correctly, you can install the NuGet package "BundlerMinifier" which will add build time support through MSBuild now in .NET Core apps too